# Printing in Win32

Tags: winapi

I have this program that is supposed to print a rectangle on the printer. It uses standard Win32 API calls.

```
HANDLE hdl;
DEVMODE* devmode;
OpenPrinter(L"HP Deskjet F4400 series", &hdl, NULL);
int size = DocumentProperties(NULL, hdl, L"HP Deskjet F4400 series", NULL, NULL, 0);
devmode = (DEVMODE*)malloc(size);
DocumentProperties(NULL, hdl, L"HP Deskjet F4400 series", devmode, NULL, DM_OUT_BUFFER);
HDC printerDC = CreateDC(L"WINSPOOL", devmode->dmDeviceName, NULL, devmode);
DOCINFO info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
StartDoc(printerDC, &info);
StartPage(printerDC);
Rectangle(printerDC, 100, 100, 200, 200);
EndPage(printerDC);
EndDoc(printerDC);
DeleteDC(printerDC);
```

All the API calls succeed, but no printing happens. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I would suggest posting this to a Haskell-specific group.

Comment: Have you made your own openPrinter, printerDC, startDoc ..... functions?  I think you better give a more complete sample of your code.

Comment: You're not closing the printer handle with `ClosePrinter`, at the very least.

Comment: More information: when I run the code, a print job briefly appears in the Print Spooler, then disappears.

Comment: Also, for some reason it works perfectly with XPS document writer, just not with my printer.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of issues here:

1. You're not closing the printer with `ClosePrinter`
2. The parameters to `OpenPrinter` and `CreateDC` are incorrect - they need to be an actual printer name, not a printer class.  (When I tried your code, the APIs failed.)

I tweaked the GDI print sample to print to the default printer, and it works; I modified your sample appropriately:

```
HANDLE hdl;
DEVMODE* devmode;
wchar_t szPrinter[MAX_PATH];
DWORD cchPrinter(ARRAYSIZE(szPrinter));
GetDefaultPrinter(szPrinter, &cchPrinter);
OpenPrinter(szPrinter, &hdl, NULL);
int size = DocumentProperties(NULL, hdl, szPrinter, NULL, NULL, 0);
devmode = (DEVMODE*)malloc(size);
DocumentProperties(NULL, hdl, szPrinter, devmode, NULL, DM_OUT_BUFFER);
HDC printerDC = CreateDC(L"WINSPOOL", szPrinter, NULL, devmode);
DOCINFO info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
StartDoc(printerDC, &info);
StartPage(printerDC);
Rectangle(printerDC, 100, 100, 200, 200);
EndPage(printerDC);
EndDoc(printerDC);
DeleteDC(printerDC);
ClosePrinter(hdl);
```

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between a printer name and a printer class? On my system, GetDefaultPrinter returns exactly the string I had in place of szPrinter.

Comment: Interesting - on my system, GetDefaultPrinter returned a network path.  I wonder what would happen if you had two HP 4400 printers installed?

Comment: @user2817408 One really important change is to avoid using `devmode->dmDeviceName` in the `CreateDC` call - `dmDeviceName` is fixed-length, and it's really easy to have printer names that are larger than that size, resulting in failures.